# Download a GridView into PDF including English and Arabic text in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, utf-8, arabic

Can anyone help me out with my subjected issue.
I've VS 2019 and I need to download my GridView into PDF. Where English is working fine but there issue with Arabic text. Please help me out.
My print and export to excel works just fine.
Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a winforms GridView or and ASP.NET GridView?
Which component or library do you use to convert the GridView contents to PDF?
What has Excel to do with the GridView of VS 2019?

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the reply.
I'm using webforms with iTextSharp for PDF to download.
For the excel I just tell that its work fine when I download my gridview data into Excel.